# Latency in Iterator or foreach

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, iterator

i have one ArrayList that has a 1000 Insert SQL statement. but rather in execution time the latency of Iterator or (enhanced for loop) for this ArrayList take **1 minute** . and my JFrame is not responding in this period. what can i do?  Thanks

```
 Iterator itr = stms.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {                

            DB_STM.executeUpdate((String) itr.next());
        }
```

Comment: Post the whole code!

Comment: Don't blame the iterator, it's the `executeUpdate` that makes it slow.

Comment: Don't execute slow code in the event dispatch thread. Use a SwingWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` internally uses `iterator` only, in order to handle bulk updates and inserts from JDBC, you can use batch updates using `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` of `PreparedStatement` as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28752)

> This issue just related to internal latency of loops. Are you agree
> with me ?

No, I don't agree. Basically, there are few design issues with your code.

(1) You should handle bulk & costly (in terms of time) operations in the background (like using `SwingWorker` as others suggested).

(2) Use JDBC `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` to reduce the database hits & improves the performance.

Comment: Thanks my dear. The problem is exist!. This issue just related to internal latency of loops. are you agree with me ?

Comment: thanks for your comment. i found the problem. because my db is mySQL coummunity!. i'am copy the pure SQL Statement in query area in the mysql. the situation is that. 40 seconds for 1000 insert Statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should not run long operations in Swing AWT Event Thread. Use SwingWorker for this.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html